# Running multiple worker daemons SLURM

Tags: cluster-computing, distributed-computing, distributed-system, slurm

I want to run multiple worker daemons on single machine. As per [damienfrancois's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763614/damienfrancois) answer on [what is the minimum number of computers for a slurm cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685320/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-computers-for-a-slurm-cluster) it can be done. Problem is currently I am able to execute only 1 worker daemon on one machine. for example

When I run

```
sudo slurmd -N linux1 -cDvv
sudo slurmd -N linux2 -cDvv
```

linux1 goes down when I run linux2. Is it possible to run multiple worker daemons on one machine?
Here is my [slurm.conf](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmoHyXoUBs4ia0vZADpKuPD0aoc) file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as your intention seems to be just testing the behavior of Slurm, I would recommend you to use the *front-end mode*, where you can create dummy computation nodes in the same machine.

In their [FAQ](https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#multi_slurmd), you have more details, but basically you must configure your installation to work with this mode:

```
./configure --enable-front-end
```

And configure the nodes in *slurm.conf*

```
NodeName=test[1-100] NodeHostName=localhost
```

In that guide, they also explain how to launch more than one real daemons in the same node by changing the ports, but for my testing purposes it was not necessary.

Good luck!

Comment: I configured installation as mentioned above but the still only one worker daemon running.

Comment: @PaulSchimmer Yes! But it emulates all the nodes. Try to execute a `sinfo` and you'll see.

Comment: Should be add `CPUs=1 RealMemory=7954` etc as well? or does it automatically handles it? and shoul 100 equal to number of processors on the node?

Comment: If it is for testing slurm behavior, you should not care about how many processors you have. However, if you are willing to execute workloads not oversubscribing CPUs would be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue as you, I resolved it by modifying the paths of log files as mentioned there [multiple slurmd support](https://slurm.schedmd.com/programmer_guide.html#multiple_slurmd_support).
In your slurm.conf for example

```
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmd.log
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
```

must be

```
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmd.%n.log
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.%n.pid
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd.%n
```

Now you can launch multiple slurmd.

Note : I tried with your slurm conf, I think some parameters are missing like define two NodeName instead of one and add which Port to use for each of Nodes.
This works for me

```
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=linux[1-10] NodeHostname=linux0 Port=17004 CPUs=1 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=linux[11-19] NodeHostname=linux0 Port=17005 CPUs=1 State=UNKNOWN
# PARTITIONS
PartitionName=main Nodes=linux1  Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
PartitionName=dev Nodes=linux11  Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```