# Unable to run multiple jobs parallel in slurm >= v20 using emulate mode

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

My goal is to set up a single server `slurm` cluster (only using a single computer) that can run multiple jobs in parallel.

In my node `nproc` returns 4 so I believe I can run 4 jobs in parallel if they use a single core. In order to do it I run the controller and the worker daemon on the same node.
When I submit four jobs at the same time, only one of them is able to run and the other three are not able to run due to the following error: `queued and waiting for resources`.

I am using `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"`. I have observe that this approach works on tag version `<=19` with the `slurm.conf` configuration file I write bottom:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm ~/slurm && cd ~/slurm
$ git checkout e2e21cb571ce88a6dd52989ec6fe30da8c4ef15f  #slurm-19-05-8-1` 
$ ./configure --enable-debug --enable-front-end --enable-multiple-slurmd
$ sudo make && sudo make install
```

but does not work on higher versions like >= `slurm 20.02.1` or its `master` branch. All release versions could be seens here (https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/tags).

---

```sh
❯ sinfo
Sat Nov 06 14:17:04 2021
NODELIST   NODES PARTITION       STATE CPUS    S:C:T MEMORY TMP_DISK WEIGHT AVAIL_FE REASON
home1          1    debug*        idle 1       1:1:1      1        0      1   (null) none
home2          1    debug*        idle 1       1:1:1      1        0      1   (null) none
home3          1    debug*        idle 1       1:1:1      1        0      1   (null) none
home4          1    debug*        idle 1       1:1:1      1        0      1   (null) none
$ srun -N1 sleep 10  # runs
$ srun -N1 sleep 10  # queued and waiting for resources
$ srun -N1 sleep 10  # queued and waiting for resources
$ srun -N1 sleep 10  # queued and waiting for resources
```

Here, I get lost where since its [emulate-mode](https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#multi_slurmd) they should be able to run in parallel.

They way I build from the source-code:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm ~/slurm && cd ~/slurm
./configure --enable-debug --enable-multiple-slurmd
make
sudo make install
```

---

```sh
$ hostname -s
home
$ nproc
4
```

###### Compute_node setup:

```
NodeName=home[1-4] NodeHostName=home NodeAddr=127.0.0.1 CPUs=1 ThreadsPerCore=1 Port=17001
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP Shared=FORCE:1
```

I have also tried: `NodeHostName=localhost`

`slurm.conf` file:

```sh
ControlMachine=home  # $(hostname -s)
ControlAddr=127.0.0.1
ClusterName=cluster
SlurmUser=alper
MailProg=/home/user/slurm_mail_prog.sh
MinJobAge=172800  # 48 h
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmd.%n.log
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.%n.pid
AuthType=auth/munge
CryptoType=crypto/munge
MpiDefault=none
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPort=6820
SlurmctldPort=6821
StateSaveLocation=/tmp/slurmstate
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/none
InactiveLimit=0
Waittime=0
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/linear
PriorityDecayHalfLife=0
PriorityUsageResetPeriod=NONE
AccountingStorageEnforce=limits
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/slurmdbd
AccountingStoreFlags=YES
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
NodeName=home[1-2] NodeHostName=home NodeAddr=127.0.0.1 CPUs=2 ThreadsPerCore=1 Port=17001
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP Shared=FORCE:1
```

`slurmdbd.conf`:

```sh
AuthType=auth/munge
AuthInfo=/var/run/munge/munge.socket.2
DbdAddr=localhost
DbdHost=localhost
SlurmUser=alper
DebugLevel=4
LogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmdbd.log
PidFile=/var/run/slurmdbd.pid
StorageType=accounting_storage/mysql
StorageUser=alper
StoragePass=12345
```

The way I run slurm:

```sh
sudo /usr/local/sbin/slurmd 
sudo /usr/local/sbin/slurmdbd &
sudo /usr/local/sbin/slurmctld -cDvvvvvv
```

---

### Update

I have compiled in the latest tag `slurm-21-08-4-1` using `./configure --enable-debug --enable-front-end` in order to test in (`non-emulator mode`):

```
git checkout slurm-21-08-4-1
./configure --enable-debug --enable-multiple-slurmd
make
sudo make install
```

I have following lines in my `/usr/local/etc/slurm.conf` file:

For:

```
NodeName=home NodeAddr=127.0.0.1 CPUs=4
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

I get following error: `slurmd: fatal: Frontend not configured correctly in slurm.conf. See FrontEndName in slurm.conf man page.`

When I try:

```
FrontEndName=home
```

I get following error message:

```
$ sudo slurmd -Dvvv
slurmd: debug:  Log file re-opened
slurmd: error: _find_node_record: lookup failure for node "home"
slurmd: error: _find_node_record: lookup failure for node "home", alias "home"
slurmd: error: slurmd initialization failed
```

Than when I have tried following:

```
FrontEndName=127.0.0.1
NodeName=home NodeHostName=localhost NodeAddr=127.0.0.1 CPUs=4
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

which keeps all the submitted jobs in a pending state with following error message:

`slurmctld: error: _slurm_rpc_node_registration node=home: Invalid node name specified`

Related:

- minimum number of computers for a slurm cluster (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27788311/2402577)
- [Running multiple worker daemons SLURM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40707189/2402577)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009930/2402577

Comment: I am not sure that emulation is the right approach here.  Can't you just define your machine as a single node with 4 cores?

Comment: I have also tried that where building via `./configure --enable-debug --enable-front-end` (without the emulation) with following line in the conf  `NodeName=home[1-2] NodeHostName=home NodeAddr=127.0.0.1 CPUs=1`, but I won't be able to make it work on slurm versions  >= v20 as well

Comment: You only have one node with 4 cores, so you want something like ```NodeName=home CPUs=4```. You shouldn't need ```NodeHostName``` and maybe not ```NodeAddr``` if the hostname is properly resolved in your network, i.e your machine is actually called ```home``` (if not, maybe you do need to set it to```127.0.0.1```).

Comment: @loris I have tried your advice please see the update part in my question related to non-emulator mode with the latest tag of slurm tryout

Comment: Is your machine really called ```home```? Is that what ```hostname``` says?  If not and it is actually, say, ```pcalper```, then maybe it is enough to set ```FrontEndName=pcalper``` and ```NodeName=pcalper CPUs=4```.  As I have never tried this, I am guessing.  You probably should write to the Slurm mailing list.

Comment: @loris Yes hostname returns `home`. Actually I wrote to Slurm mailing list but I haven't get a proper response from them (https://groups.google.com/g/slurm-users/c/80fGRnaU-mI) . My actual question is simple where I just want to able to run `slurm` in single server. With the `slurm.conf` file I was able to make it work in the `slurm-19-05-8-1`but I cannot with the higher versions.

Comment: So what error do you get if you just set  ```FrontEndName=home NodeName=home CPUs=4```?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239488/discussion-between-loris-and-alper).